# Javascript Mapping Issue

Tags: javascript, mapping

I'm pretty new to Javascript and Mapping is a bit confusing and need a bit of help. I have a record set of an array of objects, each object has the same name but the other 3 elements in the object are different. The array looks like this

```
[ { Name: 'MyGroupName',
    App_Name: 'App Name 1',
    App_ID: '1',
    App_Members: 32 },
  { Name: 'MyGroupName',
    CI_Name: 'App Name 2',
    Apps_ID: '2',
    App_Members: 96 },
  { Name: 'MyGroupName',
    CI_Name: 'App Name 3',
    Apps_ID: '2',
    App_Members: 348 }
]
```

I'm looking to make the group them together using the Name so when displaying on the screen i don't get the name repeated over and over. So i need to make my return array look something like this

```
let example = {
'MyGroupName': [
    { 
      App_Name: 'App Name 1',
      App_ID: '1',
      App_Members: 32 
    },
    { 
      CI_Name: 'App Name 2',
      Apps_ID: '2',
      App_Members: 96 
    },
    { 
      CI_Name: 'App Name 3',
      Apps_ID: '2',
      App_Members: 348 
    }
  ]
```

I have started off with the below code but i've hit a brick wall and its confusing me, any help would be appreciated.

```
.then(function (recordSet) {
   let groupToArrayOfApps = {}

   for(let record in recordSet) {
       // todo: add group name as key to the map & app name to array of apps
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you just need to check if `record.Name` already exist as a property in  `groupToArrayOfApps`

```js
let recordSet = [ { Name: 'MyGroupName',
    App_Name: 'App Name 1',
    App_ID: '1',
    App_Members: 32 },
  { Name: 'MyGroupName',
    CI_Name: 'App Name 2',
    Apps_ID: '2',
    App_Members: 96 },
  { Name: 'MyGroupName',
    CI_Name: 'App Name 3',
    Apps_ID: '2',
    App_Members: 348 }
];

let groupToArrayOfApps = {};

recordSet.forEach(function(record){
  // Check if property already exists, if not add it as empty array
  if(!groupToArrayOfApps[record.Name]) groupToArrayOfApps[record.Name] = [];
  // Prepare the record to be added (without Name property)
  let addRecord = Object.assign({}, record);
  // Add the desired record to the property array
  groupToArrayOfApps[record.Name].push(addRecord);
});

console.log(groupToArrayOfApps);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that worked a treat! But can I ask if you know how I could add the GroupName as a Key? I still need something in order to reference it.

Comment: @Rossa could you update your expected output to reflect that so I can see what you're expecting? Do you mean keep the `Name` property?

Comment: Yeah i would like to keep the Name property so I am able to reference it to display in HTML using angularjs. So my HTML looks something like this.

Comment: <div ng-repeat="item in data" class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{item.Name}}">{{item.Name}}</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse{{item.Name}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">{{item.App_Name}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: I've updated the response. If you run the snippet you should see the outcome you want

Comment: Cheers, thats the one!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object for the result and delete the property `Name` in a copy of the object.

```js
var data = [{ Name: 'MyGroupName', App_Name: 'App Name 1', App_ID: '1', App_Members: 32 }, { Name: 'MyGroupName', CI_Name: 'App Name 2', Apps_ID: '2', App_Members: 96 }, { Name: 'MyGroupName', CI_Name: 'App Name 3', Apps_ID: '2', App_Members: 348 }],
    grouped = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var o = Object.assign({}, a);
    delete o.Name;
    grouped[a.Name] = grouped[a.Name] || [];
    grouped[a.Name].push(o);
});

console.log(grouped);
```

If you don't mind to mutate the original object, you could use a version without copying properties and just delete the unwanted property `Name`.

```js
var data = [{ Name: 'MyGroupName', App_Name: 'App Name 1', App_ID: '1', App_Members: 32 }, { Name: 'MyGroupName', CI_Name: 'App Name 2', Apps_ID: '2', App_Members: 96 }, { Name: 'MyGroupName', CI_Name: 'App Name 3', Apps_ID: '2', App_Members: 348 }],
    grouped = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(function (a) {
    grouped[a.Name] = grouped[a.Name] || [];
    grouped[a.Name].push(a);
    delete a.Name;
});

console.log(grouped);
```